# How to get response from Curl if post was successfull or not?

Tags: c++, curl

i am using curl in c++ problem is that i am able to get error response if connection to server was not made due to wrong address or any other reason but i am not able to get response if data to the server was successfully posted.
i changed the name of my php file on the server to which i am trying to send data but curl response was curl_ok i guess curle_ok is just for checking connection with server and not with the page on that server
so is there any way through which i can acknowledge if my data was successfully send to the php page i am trying to send from my c++ client side?

Answer (score 1):

got it working with this

```
    int curl_code = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    long http_code = 0;
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &http_code);
    if (http_code == 200 && curl_code != CURLE_ABORTED_BY_CALLBACK)
    {
        cout << "Successfully posted the data";
    }
    else if (http_code == 404)
    {
        cout<<"Error code 404";
    }
```